# position element over image

Tags: html, css

I am having some weird problems trying to position the `h3` tag over the image `.featured-image`(Sitting on top of the image). When I try `position: absolute;` .. If the content in `<p>` is more or less, the `h3` will move from its position. If I try `position: relative;` theres a big gap from the image and if I tried to `margin` `<p>` closer or farther, the position also moves. If I wrap another `div` around the `h3` tag with `position relative;` and then leave `h3` as `position: absolute;`. It fixes it but that seems such a hack.

**HTML:**

```
 <section class="featured">
              <h1><img src="images/icon-featured.png" width="24px" height="23px" alt="Featured Site Icon"> Featured Site </h1>
              <div class="image-wrap">
                <a href="#">
                  <img class="featured-image" src="images/content-images/image.jpg" width="399px" height= "37px" alt="" />
                </a>
                <h3> Lorem Ipsum </h3>
              </div> <!-- image-wrap -->
              <p> 
                <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.
                incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.
                exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
              </p>
        </section><!-- .featured -->
```

CSS

```
article h1 img { margin: 0 5px 0 0; }
article .featured { }
article .featured h1 {  }
article .featured .image-wrap { margin: 27px 0 0 0; text-align: center; }
article .featured .image-wrap img { border: 1px solid #8e8d8e; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4); -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
   -o-box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4); box-shadow: 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4); }

article .featured .image-wrap h3 { background: rgba(23, 23, 23, .5); bottom: 66px; font-size: 23px; padding: 10px; position: relative; left: 190px;
   text-align: right; width: 230px;  }

article .featured p { margin: 25px auto; padding: 10px; width: 380px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position .image-wrap relatively, but without any left/right/top/bottom properties. Then, position the h3 absolutely and move it to where you want it.

The problem you're encountering is that absolutely positioned elements have to be contained in a non-statically positioned ancestor element, otherwise it defaults to positioning it relative to the html element (that's probably why it was affected by the following paragraph). Relatively positioned elements are still part of the page flow, so the space relatively positioned elements would originally have taken up is preserved. That's the extra space you're seeing.

The w3c has a nice intro to css positioning: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp, as does this page: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Almost. Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to their nearest ancestor that has a non-static position, that may be `<html>` or something else.

Comment: Could i do this with section and remove .image-wrap? I was only doing that to wrap the h3 and image.

Comment: @Trippy: You could but then you'd have to account for the size of the `<h1>` somehow. Your `<div class=".image-wrap"/>` gives you a convenient upper-left corner for positioning your `<h3>`. You could try putting the `<h3>` inside the `<a>` and put `position:relative` on the `<a>` though. Separating markup and presentation is a nice goal but it doesn't always work.

Comment: @mu is too short - absolutely right. I completely conflated parent and ancestor in my head. :P I corrected it in my answer.